# How to find the test that caused a timeout

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, vstest

At least one of my tests hangs and causes the test run to abort eventually:

```
Aborting test run: test run timeout of 7200000 milliseconds exceeded.
Results File: D:\TF\2\s\TestResults\xxxxx.trx
Test Run Aborted.
Total tests: Unknown
  Passed: 3261
 Skipped: 1
Total time: 2,0003 Hours
##[warning]Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.
```

I'm using TFS 2018 and the `Visual Studio Test` task (2.3.28) to run unit tests built with Visual Studio 2019 16.4.5.
I started the test task with the additional parameters: `/Blame -- RunConfiguration.TestSessionTimeout=7200000`

A few days ago, the test suite ran successfully. It typically finishes within 10 minutes:

```
Results File: D:\TF\3\s\TestResults\xxxxxx.trx
Test Run Successful.
Total tests: 3336
  Passed: 3335
 Skipped: 1
Total time: 9.0574 Minutes
```

I examined the .trx file and found the test that was skipped.
But there was no hint about the tests that were skipped due to the abortion and what test caused the time out.

How do I find the problematic test?

**Edit:**

When examining the .trx file, display the `Start Time` column and sort it descending. The tests that most recently started may indicate which DLL may be the culprit. Alas, that doesn't provide a definite answer which test(s) were running when the timeout occurred.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want information like the screenshot below, you need to use Visual Studio 2019 to do the tests.

[image]

The definition looks like below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your advice, which is not helpful, though.

Comment: ... [accidently submitted my last comment and wasn't allowed to complete it.]

The build agent has already a full Visual Studio installation, so inserting the VsTest Platform Installer to install a NuGet Package for a feature that is not missing, is pointless.
Therefore, the Visual Studio Test tasks already works and also displays the timings shown in your screen shot. The highest timing was [4m 35s], thus still no hint about which test got stuck.